# Unable to write to Google Sheets ((400) Bad Request)

Tags: powershell, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to write to a private Google Sheets document using the API and PowerShell web requests. I know I have handled the authentication correctly as I can read from a sheet just fine using the following code:

```
$read = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$sheet/values/Sheet1!A1:B2?access_token=$($token.access_token)"
```

The issue arises when I attempt to write to that same sheet (after clearing all content from the cells):

```
$json = @”
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:D2",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    ["Door", "15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
    ["Engine", "100", "1", "3/20/2016"]
  ]
}
“@

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$sheet/values/Sheet1!A1:D2:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&access_token=$($token.access_token)" -Method Post -Body $json
```

I get:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to check the documentation [Google Sheets API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) to understand the correct structure of request and proper authorization. Receiving a 400: Bad Request mean there is something invalid in your request. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Do you see any difference between the structure of my query and that on the Quickstart page?

Comment: @saltface Try adding `-ContentType "application/json"` to your `Invoke-WebRequest`. I'm not sure if this will fix your issue but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Toomaja We have a winner! Make your comment into an answer and I'll accept it. I can't believe it was something so simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Invoke-WebRequest` is missing the `ContentType` parameter, which is necessary when your `Method` is set to a verb for sending data (such as `Post`).

> > The purpose of the Content-Type field is to describe the data contained in the body fully enough that the receiving user agent can pick an appropriate agent or mechanism to present the data to the user, or otherwise deal with the data in an appropriate manner.
>
> [The Content-Type Header Field](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)

In your case, the parameter will be `-ContentType "application/json"`. For example:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$sheet/values/Sheet1!A1:D2:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&access_token=$($token.access_token)" -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $json
```

[Invoke-WebRequest ContentType Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest#-contenttype)